# access user variable names in llvm ir pass

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I am totally newbie to llvm . I want to count the number of accesses to user defined variables by writing a llvm pass over it.

I need to know how do i get all the variables that are there in the source file and are not llvm ir generated temporaries. I know i can iterate over all the instructions and see if its a load store instruction [or an instruction that may write or read from memory]. But how do i know which variables are user defined and which are temporaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing you need to approach this is to use [the source-level debug information](http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html) embedded in the module.

If you want to solve your problem on unoptimized code, you should probably go over all `alloca` instructions, and for each instruction that is associated with a variable (via `llvm.dbg.declare`), track all the stores and loads to that memory.

Things get much, much messier on optimized code - not just because now you need to take `llvm.dbg.value` into consideration, but because accesses to that variable will mostly be indirect, so you'll have to do more than just check where the value is used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply  ! Since i am using unoptimized code , i can simply iterate over all the alloca instructions and store variables name ... But isn't this true only for local variables ? Global variables donot have an allca instruction associated as far as i know !

Comment: @killx correct, global variables work differently. Just go over all of them - [they appear in the debug metadata](http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html#global-variable-descriptors) - and check stores and loads to those values. By the way, you can find an example implementation on how to iterate those (and other debug structures) in [the implementation of `DebugInfoFinder`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1DebugInfoFinder.html#a217bc3f8a611fdaf301fa67d86994c32).